# List View Threshold

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I have a Sharepoint List that exceeded 5000 items limit today. After reading numerous suggestions, I:

- indexed columns
- Created a filtered default view that returns 3000 items.

Even though the default view now returns only 3000 items. In the List Settings Page I still see an error message saying "The number of items in this list exceeds the list view threshold, which is 5000 items. Tasks that cause excessive server load are currently prohibited. Could you please let me know what could be an issue and why filtering and indexing didn't help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Please do the following troubleshooting:**

1.Columns with column types like **people, lookup, or managed metadata** can cause list view threshold errors when sorting. Therefore, we recommend that you can use **text, number, date, and other column types** in the first sort.

2.Displaying **12 or more columns** of the following types can cause a list view threshold error: **people, lookup, and managed metadata.** Displaying columns of other types will not.

3.Clear the browser cache or test with another browser.